# Where to download Xamarin.Android(8.3.3) release

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, mvvmcross, visual-studio-mac

I am working with a legacy Xamarin project, unfortunately I took Visual studio latest updates, after which every class under PCL shows "Default system.object is not defined or imported", many such errors.

Upon close inspection I found, in core project all references under .Net Protable subset is missing. Though, the project is compiling, I am not able to use autocomplete feature in core project.

Hence, I decided to downgrade my setup to what it was, I was able to download Visual studio for Mac and Xamarin.iOS early releases from[Here](https://releases.xamarin.com/category/visual-studio-for-mac/)

But, I am not able to find the link to download Xamarin.Android package for Mac.

I tried all manual things, I am not able to get the Xamarin.Android setup done with early release (8.3.3).[image: Error I am getting]

Any helps in this regard is highly appreciated.

ScreenShot of errors is attached.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I searched my archives and Xamarin.Android 8.3.3-? was released as a part of Visual Studio For Mac 7.5.2.40.

- Download link: https://dl.xamarin.com/MonoforAndroid/Mac/xamarin.android-8.3.3-2.pkg

> For more information on this release, and to see all the issues that have been addressed, see the release notes: https://developer.xamarin.com/releases/android/xamarin.android_8/xamarin.android_8.3/

```
xml2 < index.xml | grep "/ArrayOfUpdate/Update/Url" | cut -d'=' -f 2
https://dl.xamarin.com/MonoFrameworkMDK/Macx86/MonoFramework-MDK-5.10.1.57.macos10.xamarin.universal.pkg
https://dl.xamarin.com/VsMac/VisualStudioForMac-7.5.2.40.dmg
https://dl.xamarin.com/profiler/profiler-mac-1.6.2-165.pkg
https://dl.xamarin.com/MonoforAndroid/Mac/xamarin.android-8.3.3-2.pkg
https://dl.xamarin.com/MonoforAndroid/Mac/xamarin.android-8.3.99-12.pkg
https://dl.xamarin.com/XamarinforMac/Mac/xamarin.mac-4.4.1.193.pkg
https://dl.xamarin.com/MonoTouch/Mac/xamarin.ios-11.12.0.4.pkg
```